# Database view in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, local-database

I have created my database in my windows phone app. Now i want to see whether it is created and stored data as i programmed it. But i am failed to view this database. Where my local database file get saved ? I like to mentioned that i have stored the database in the isolated storage. I heard about a method by using firefox extension i may be able to see the database but not sure what extension that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard about any Firefox extensions for browsing Isolated Storage on Windows Phone.

You can use [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to copy your data file from the emulator or device to your desktop. If you're using Linq to Sql, you can open it in SQL Server Management Studio. Other data formats (i.e., Sqlite) can be opened in respective administration tools.

Answer (score 0):

After Downloading Windows Phone power tools as mentioned by Michael, you can easily extract the database.
You may find difficulty in finding the exact file as the apps are listed by GUID and not their names in wp power tools.So you may have to go through each app to see which one contains the desired file.
Once you have located the file you will need a viewer (like [this](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/SDF-Viewer-Download-146403.html)) to open the file.

This method worked for me just right.